# List of Array tcl

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I have 5 arrays and i want to iterate over them one by one, so I'm thinking to add these arrays to another array and access them one by one with indexes

```
array set ListOfArrays {1 $array1 2 $array2 3 $array3 4 $array4 5 $array5}
for { set i 1} { $i <= 5 } {incr i} {
    set list $ListOfArrays($i)
    foreach {key} [array names list] {
        puts $key
    }
}
```

The output is empty...

what is wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl's arrays can't be put in a list; they're (collections of) variables, not values. But you can put the *names* of the arrays in.

```
array set ListOfArrays {1 array1 2 array2 3 array3 4 array4 5 array5}
for { set i 1} { $i <= 5 } {incr i} {
    upvar 0 $ListOfArrays($i) list
    foreach {key} [array names list] {
        puts $key
    }
}
```

The `upvar 0`? It makes a *local alias* to a variable, and it's great for this sort of thing.

Comment: I was thinking about using `upvar` but you wrote it faster :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `array`-based solutions, a solution using dictionaries. I borrow the data from Jerry's answer.

```
set dict1 {1 a 2 b}
set dict2 {3 c 4 d}
set dict3 {5 e 6 f}
set dict4 {7 g 8 h}
set dict5 {9 i 10 j}

set dicts [list $dict1 $dict2 $dict3 $dict4 $dict5]

foreach dict $dicts {
    foreach key [dict keys $dict] {
        puts $key
    }
}
```

Unlike arrays, dictionaries can be passed as values and evaluated using `$`. This means that you *can* put your five dictionaries in a list and traverse that list with `foreach`. In the inner loop, each key is printed.

```
foreach dict $dicts {
    dict for {key -} $dict {
        puts $key
    }
}
```

is basically the same thing.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)